# Load local json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xmlhttprequest, local

I want to create a simple local website to visualize my json data that is generated from my protractor tests. The problem is angular doesn't support loading local files, so do you know if there is any way I can use this JSON locally? I don't want to setup a server just to load a single small file to a single variable.

I tried `$http`, but that obviously throws `XMLHttpRequest Cross origin request`.
I appreciate any suggestion.

**EDIT:**
I decided to run http-server from npm. I start it on port 8080 and specify path to my project. Then I have

```
var app = angular.module("reportingApp", ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $scope.title = 'abc';

    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/e2e-Report/combined.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.title = data.jsonData;
        });
}]);
```

in my `app.js` to get the file via `http`, but it throws `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: Angular supports loading local JSOn

Comment: You can't do this

Comment: this isn't a restriction of angular, it's a restriction of your browser and a safety feature. you wouldn't want any website with javascript to be able to access your harddrive.

Comment: So is there no possible way of reading local files?

Comment: you can run your project on localhost, it will fetch local json data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Local server by installing
 `npm install http-server -g`

Once it is installed, go to command line ->Path to your project ->http-server &

**Ex.**

```
D:\angularProject> http-server & (Press Enter)
```

It will start localhost server: `localhost://8080`.
Open localhost://8080 on your browser.

Now,your CORS issue will not there. Enjoy.

EDIT: You need `node` to be installed in your machine.

Sample code:

```
$http.get("api/my.json").then(function (res){
            console.log("res",res);

        })
```

Comment: I did it but after I use $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/e2e-Report/combined.json') it throws No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Can you tell me are you using Local JSON or 127.0.0.1:8080/e2e-Report/combined.json' points to some other machine.

Comment: I run http-server (the one from your answer) with path to my local project on my local machine as an additional parameter.

Comment: @FCin your code should work. Can you Try:$http.get('e2e-Report/combined.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.title = data.jsonData;
        });

Comment: it throws 'Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes', so it doesn't use the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126232/discussion-between-ved-and-fcin).

Answer (score 0):

easy way use some editors like **Brackets** for this kind of works, with live view u get what u want.